# Micro transactions with xna on windows phone

Tags: windows, xna-4.0

Hi I've been reading around and a few sources have said that there is a way to do mircrotransactions on the windows phone but I'm having trouble on learning exactly how, can someone please help me point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of setting this up for production is that creating the products for your app happens during the app submission process. You will see an optional link for "In-app Purchases"

Instead of giving you a wall of text (the article on making this happen has many parts, visit MSDN for [Windows Phone Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for "In-app purchases"). Microsoft has a very well documented sample on how to allow the user of your app make a purchase from within the app for a production environment and a sample for mock testing via the link above.

I will summarize the major points of this process for mock testing:

1. Download the mock in-app purchase library and sample app from the [Mock In-App Purchase Library](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=269984).
2. The mock in-app purchase library is written in C# code.
   In each .cs file that you use in-app purchase functionality, include the following using statement code block:

C#

```
#if DEBUG
using MockIAPLib;
using Store = MockIAPLib;
#else
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Store;
#endif
```

This statement allows you to switch between testing in-app purchase by using the mock library or making real in-app purchase calls as a published app. When you test, you must build your app in debug mode. For debug mode, in the Solution Configurations drop-down list in Visual Studio, click Debug. When you’re ready to build your app for Windows Phone Store deployment, change to release mode by selecting Release from the Solution Configurations drop-down list.
To initialize the mock library, add the following code to the App.xaml.cs file at the end of the App constructor:

C#

```
 SetupMockIAP();
```

Then, add the SetupMockIAP method to initialize the mock library and add factious products. A sample SetupMockIAP method looks like the following:

C#

```
        private void SetupMockIAP()
        {
#if DEBUG
            MockIAP.Init();

            MockIAP.RunInMockMode(true);
            MockIAP.SetListingInformation(1, "en-us", "A description", "1", "TestApp");

            // Add some more items manually.
            ProductListing p = new ProductListing
            {
                Name = "img.2",
                ImageUri = new Uri("/Res/Image/2.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
                ProductId = "img.2",
                ProductType = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.ProductType.Durable,
                Keywords = new string[] { "image" },
                Description = "An image",
                FormattedPrice = "1.0",
                Tag = string.Empty
            };
            MockIAP.AddProductListing("img.2", p);
#endif
        }
```

Notice that the code contained in the method will be executed only when the project is running in debug mode.
An alternate way to populate the in-app purchase products is to use an XML snippet that lists all the offers you want to use for testing.
The XML looks like the following:

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProductListings>
    <ProductListing Key="test1" Purchased="true" Fulfilled="true">
        <Name>Testproduct</Name>
        <Description>A sample product listing</Description>
        <ProductId>test.durable.1</ProductId>
        <ProductType>Durable</ProductType>
        <FormattedPrice>$1.00</FormattedPrice>
        <ImageUri></ImageUri>
        <Keywords>test;product</Keywords>
        <Tag>Additional text</Tag>
    </ProductListing>
</ProductListings>
```

To load this XML in the "Mock Store", you use the following method call:

C#

```
MockIAP.PopulateIAPItemsFromXml(Xml);
```

To perform this from XNA you will need to create an interface for the user to actually purchase the item. There is a great tutorial on this on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone-45--Adding-In-App-Purchase-as-a-light-up-feature-to-your-Windows-Phone-7-Games) that talks about "Adding In App Purchase as a ‘light up’ feature to your Windows Phone 7 Games" and they offer the source code via the same link.

As a final thought, if you don't feel totally comfortable with XNA quite yet, I encourage to build a simple C#/XAML Windows Phone app to text this process. Once you have a working example, the code will be able to be moved to XNA with minimal effort. That way you can at least wrap your brain around the concept before dealing with the nuances of XNA.

If you have any questions after review the material above please let me know and I'll be happy to help.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)